# add to array the result that came from $.each

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to tweak [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) to cater my needs. I want to make an array like (refer below)

```
categories: ['2015-04-07', '2015-08-07', '2015-12-07', '2015-16-07', '2015-20-07', '2015-24-07', 2015-28-07', '2015-22-07', '2015-26-07', '2015-30-07', '2015-34-07', '2015-38-07']
```

and I have json stuff that parse the retrieved data eqaul to each data from above.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response.var), function(index, value){                          
 //value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim(); 
});
```

For each value.creation_date, the content is like (2015-05-14 00:00:00) so I have to use

```
replace('00:00:00', '').trim();
```

so that the result will be "2015-05-14". How to put each

```
value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim()
```

like an array to make it look like this

```
categories: ['2015-04-07', '2015-08-07', '2015-12-07', '2015-16-07', '2015-20-07', '2015-24-07', 2015-28-07', '2015-22-07', '2015-26-07', '2015-30-07', '2015-34-07', '2015-38-07']
```

i tried declaring a global var like

```
var num = "";
```

and then inside the $.each

```
num = + "," + value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim();
```

and tried to display it to see if it works

```
$("body").html(num);
```

but sadly not working. Any ideas, clues, recommendation, suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code should get you an array:

```
var num = [];    
$.each(JSON.parse(response.var), function(index, value){                          
     num.push(value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim()) ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.var);
$.each(data, function(index, value){ 
  data[index].creation_date = data[index].creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim(); 
});
```

Data which initially looked like this

```
[{
  creation_date: '2015-05-14 00:00:00'
}, {
  creation_date: '2015-05-13 00:00:00'
}, {
  creation_date: '2015-05-12 00:00:00'
}]
```

will look like this now

```
[{
  creation_date: '2015-05-14'
}, {
  creation_date: '2015-05-13'
}, {
  creation_date: '2015-05-12'
}]
```

---

Or you could just use javascript [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.var);
data.forEach(function(value, index){
  data[index].creation_date = data[index].creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, here is my solution

```
var categories = [];
$.each(JSON.parse(response.var), function(index, value){                          
  categories.push(value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim()); 
});
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

> like an array to make it look like this

```
categories: ['2015-04-07', '2015-08-07', '2015-12-07', '2015-16-07', '2015-20-07', '2015-24-07', 2015-28-07', '2015-22-07', '2015-26-07', '2015-30-07', '2015-34-07', '2015-38-07']
```

What I understand is, you are trying to form an array to feed it to Highchart as an input.

And as you mentioned you did something like,

```
num = + "," + value.creation_date.replace('00:00:00', '').trim();
```

Why? What all you need is an array. Run this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4bn3wk5/) and see the console.

```
var xAxis = {}
xAxis.categories = [];
xAxis.categories.push('2015-04-07');
xAxis.categories.push('2015-04-08');
xAxis.categories.push('2015-04-09');
xAxis.categories.push('2015-04-10');
console.log(xAxis);
console.log(xAxis.categories);
```

I recommend you go through Javascript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) concepts once..